# Why name of object2 is being showned null?

Tags: dart

```
class MyMain{
    String name;
    int mobile;
    String gender;
    String city;
  
    MyMain({this.name , this.mobile , this.gender , this.city});
}

class MySmall extends MyMain{
    int age;
    String std;
  
    MySmall({this.age , this.std , name , mobile , gender , city})
    : super();

}

main(){
    MyMain object1 =  MyMain(name:"object1" , mobile: 1234567890 , gender: "M" , city: "xyz");
    print(object1.name);
  
    MySmall object2 = MySmall( name: "object2" ,age: 20 , std: "First" , mobile: 0987654321, gender: "M" , city: "XYZ");
  print(object2.name);
}
```

I am trying to create child class and when I retrieve the name of child class it shows null , why so ? Any Solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `MySmall` does not call the constructor of the class it extends from (`MyMain`) with the parameters it needs.

The reasons this happens here is because your named arguments is optional and defaults to `null` if not specified. So when you do `super()` you are just setting all parameters in the `MyMain` constructor to `null`.

I can guess you are running without Dart null-safety (introduced with Dart 2.12) since it would have been complained about the possible assignment of `null` values on non-nullable types.

You can fix your code by changing your `MySmall` constructor to:

```
  MySmall(
      {this.age, this.std, String name, int mobile, String gender, String city})
      : super(name: name, mobile: mobile, gender: gender, city: city);
```

If we convert your code to be null-safe (and therefore compatible with Dart 2.12.0 and later) it would look like this. The `required` keyword was introduce to make it possible to have named arguments which is required to be set:

```
class MyMain {
  String name;
  int mobile;
  String gender;
  String city;

  MyMain({
    required this.name,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.gender,
    required this.city,
  });
}

class MySmall extends MyMain {
  int age;
  String std;

  MySmall({
    required this.age,
    required this.std,
    required String name,
    required int mobile,
    required String gender,
    required String city,
  }) : super(name: name, mobile: mobile, gender: gender, city: city);
}

void main() {
  MyMain object1 = MyMain(
    name: "object1",
    mobile: 1234567890,
    gender: "M",
    city: "xyz",
  );
  print(object1.name); // object1

  MySmall object2 = MySmall(
    name: "object2",
    age: 20,
    std: "First",
    mobile: 0987654321,
    gender: "M",
    city: "XYZ",
  );
  print(object2.name); // object2
}
```